# How to test only one function with tox?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, tox

I'm learning to write tests with tox. How do I test only one function with tox? For example if I want to test only `test_simple_backup_generation` from `tests/test_backup_cmd.py` of `django-backup` [extension](https://github.com/django-backup/django-backup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you define a parameter `{posargs}` in your `tox.ini` you can pass in arguments during execution. In the case of py.test, where

```
py.test -k test_simple_backup_generation
```

would only test one function:

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py35
[testenv]
deps=pytest
commands=
    pip install -e .[tests,docs]
    py.test {posargs}
```

and run like

```
tox -- -k test_simple_backup_generation
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one more question on tox/py.test [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018056/how-do-the-arguments-are-being-passed-to-test-functions-in-tox-py-test). Can you please check it?