# How do the arguments are being passed to test functions in tox/py.test?

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, tox

I'm learning to write tests with tox. How do the arguments are being passed to test functions in tox/py.test? For example in `test_simple_backup_generation` from `tests/test_backup_cmd.py` of `django-backup` [extension](https://github.com/django-backup/django-backup) there are three arguments `tmpdir`, `settings`, `db`. I don't have any idea where they came from. It's nothing said about this in tox documentation either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [pytest fixtures](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) provided by [pytest-django](http://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#fixtures) and [pytest itself](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html).